# How can i get string values from inputs rather than objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have a div and, inside that div, I’m generating dynamically input tags depending on a number wrote by the user. When the user clicks on the submit button, i have to get all the values of the inputs in an array and store it in the database. I’m using the firestore database. My problem is that whenever I tried to save the values of the inputs in the db, I have an error saying that the values of the inputs are UNDEFINED. I think the problem is in the values i'm getting from the inputs. They are not strings but objects.

Here's my htlm code :

```
<div>
        <div id='dates' ref={myRef} className='fields_container'>
            {
                array.map(index => 
                  <input key={index} type="date"/>
                )
            }
        </div>
        <div className="btn">
            <Button 
            variant="contained" 
            size="large" 
            onClick={handleClick}
            sx={
                {
                    fontSize: 25,
                    color: "black",
                    backgroundColor: "#d19c97",
                    fontFamily: "'Caveat', cursive",
                    boxShadow: "2px 2px 52px black",
                    '&:hover': {
                        backgroundColor: "black",
                        color: "white",
                        boxShadow: "2px 2px 52px black"
                    }
                }
            }
            >
                Suivant
            </Button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here is my handleClick function that is responsible of saving in the db:

```
const handleClick = async () => {
    // initialize array for the input values
    let values = []

    // save input values in array
    array.map(index => values.push(myRef.current.children[index].value))
    
    try {
        const clientRef = await doc(db, "SEANCES_COLLECTIONS", clientName)
        await setDoc(clientRef, {seances: values}, {merge: true})

        console.log('réussie !')
        setLoading(false)
    } catch (error) {
        //displaying all the input values on the console
        console.log(values)
        //displaying error saying that all my values are undefined
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

and here is the values and the error the console is displaying:

[image]

Comment: What is the average error message?

Comment: Have you tried checking what's the value of `values`?

Comment: It looks like `SecondPart.jsx` line 33 has `indexOf` which fails

Comment: @Konrad what does that mean ? the line 33 is the "console.log(error)"

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question, if you want to transform your values object into a string, you can use JSON.stringify().

```
values_string = JSON.stringify(values)
```

To do the oposite and get a object from a string, you can use JSON.parse().

```
values = JSON.parse(values_string)
```